# Trying to teleport Player in Unity 3D, position dosen't change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the Unity Starters Assets First Person Controller and trying to make the player teleport when they step on a circle. PlayerCapsule has the tag Player. This is my code;

```
public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform teleporttarget;
   

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
     
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player position: " + other.transform.position + "\n" + "Target position: " + teleporttarget.transform.position);
            other.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
           // other.transform.position = teleporttarget.transform.position;
        }
    }

}
```

The Player Position and Target Position are both being read correctly (via the debug), but the Player never teleports to the target. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I've updated the code as ge.go recommended, however the issue isn't the collision. The colliding works since I get a Debug message whenever the player touches the teleport pad. The issue is getting the Player to teleport.

PlayerCapsule is tagged as Player and is a parent to the Capsule object. PlayerCapsule has a Character Controller, a First Person Controller script, a Basic Rigid Body Push script, a Starter Assets Input script, and a Player Input.
Capsule has a Mesh Filter, a Mesh Renderer, and a Capsule Collider.
Adding a Rigidbody to either of these and setting it to IsKinematic did not change the teleportation. Note that I'm just using the default Starter Assets for this and didn't create the Player myself.

Comment: Are you sure that the event handler 'OnTriggerEnter' is the correct one? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure, when I touch the teleporter I get the Debug information about the player and target position. It's getting the player location to move that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

The Teleporter needs a `Collider` for `OnTriggerEnter()` to work properly!
Add a `Collider` `Component` to your Teleporter `GameObject` and step inside it.

Edit: At least one of the interacting objects are required to have a `Rigidbody` attached to it. There is no way around this either. In case you are using other methods of movement than using a `Rigidbody` the best solution would be to make use of [IsKinematik](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html).
Try this:

Player:

- Collider (NOT Trigger)
- Rigidbody (IsKinematik)

Teleporter:

- Collider (IsTrigger)

Also, the teleporter does not need to search for the player. You can use the `collider other` inside the `private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` to examine the tag of the entering object. Like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        other.transform.position = m_Pos;
}
```

Note that I use a `Vector3` *m_Pos* directly, rather than a Transform (which would need another `GameObject` *target* to work).

Comment: It does have a collider, and IsTrigger is true

Comment: Could you please list all the components of the player and teleporter? You can edit your post to do that. No need for a sea of comments :)

Comment: I have most likely solved the problem. I have edited my original reply to include the new information.